# get array from single firestore document with ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-hooks

I'm learning to use firebase and react. I have shared my firestore collection image. and my code for fetching the array from my document is given below.

This code is fetching the data from my firestore database and then storing the result in my watchlistMovies react state. when i try to log the react state or even data.data() it gives the desired result but when i try to map over the array or do something similar like logging **watchlistMovies.myList[0].media_type** it hits me with an error. i tried my best trying different things making it work but it breaks a thing or two in process.

I hope someone here will help me. Thank you in advance! : )

**updated the code**

```
const Watchlist = () => {

    const [watchlistMovies, setwatchlistMovies] = useState([]);
    const {currentUser} = useAuth()
    const usersCollectionRef = collection(db,"users")
    const docRef = doc(db,"users",currentUser.uid)
    
    useEffect(() => {
        const getWatchListMovies = async () => {
            const data = await getDoc(docRef)
            if (data.exists()) {
                console.log(data.data());
                setwatchlistMovies([...watchlistMovies ,data.data().myList])
            } else {
                console.log("empty");
            }
        }
        getWatchListMovies();
    }, [])
    
    console.log(watchlistMovies);

    // console.log(watchlistMovies.myList[0]);

    return (
        <div className="content-page-area">
            <h1 className="trending-text">  My Watchlist </h1>
           
            
            <Container className="watchlist-container">
            <hr/>


            {watchlistMovies.map(
            (item) => (
                <ListContent
                item_poster={item.poster_url}
                item_title={item.media_title}
                item_year={item.release_year}
                item_rating={item.media_rating}
                item_type={item.media_type}
                item_id={item.media_id}
                />
            )
            )}


            
            </Container>
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <br/>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Watchlist
```

[image: this is the image of my firestore db]

[image: error image]

[image: added console.log images]

Comment: "it hits me with an error." Can you share a screenshot of the error? Also where is your map or log statement?

Comment: i have updated the code and added error image i am still trying to fix things so i'm sorry if a few things are here and there

Comment: can you do `console.log(watchlistMovies)` and provide a screenshot?

Comment: i have updated the console.log images, sorry for the late reply

Comment: this is another user and the data associated with it so the data may vary but the schema will be same

Comment: From the screenshot you shared, I see you are getting “Objects are not valid as a React child” error.The "Objects are not valid as a React child" error happens when trying to render a collection of data by mistakenly returning the object when applying the map method instead of using the data from the object to create and return JSX. You can also refer to this https://www.g2i.co/blog/understanding-the-objects-are-not-valid-as-a-react-child-error-in-react